# jquery ajax autocomplete with PHP

Tags: jquery, database

I have a jquery function which fetches data from a database and successfully displays it as a list of countries beneath my search box. I want to click on one of the countries and have the value of the search box be populated with that country.

This is the Jquery function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".search").keyup(function() { 
    $('#result').html("looking for your country ...");
        var search = $("#search").val();
        $.get('search.php', { 'search': search }, 
        function(server_response) {
            $('#result').html(server_response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I basically need a couple of lines in the jquery function which allows me to click on`enter code here` the country and for that value to populate the search input.

Grateful for anybody's help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we see what `server_response` holds, so we know how to delegate the click function, and what selector to delegate it to?

Comment: can you post your html and php as well?

Comment: can you share the `server_response ` html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what you're returning from the server...

Please note that I'm making a lot of assumptions here.

If it's a list:

```
$('#result').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var clicked_value = $(this).text();
    $(".search").val( clicked_value );
});
```

If it's something like a select option:

```
$('#result').on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    var clicked_value = $(this).val();
    $(".search").val( clicked_value );
});
```

I haven't tested this code in any way, just wrote it down. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar, sir. It works perfectly and I am pleased because it is such an economical piece of code. The element is <div> although li works too, of course. Thank you very much.